# Unity - Clamp Rotation between arbitrary angles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, angle, quaternions

I have a task where I have to clamp an angle between other two angle.

> The catch is that the limits can be >360 or <0

(ex. [-45,45] or [275,45]).

> Is there a clean way to do this taking into account all the special
>   cases?

(ex. range [-45,45] and input angle of 225 should be -45).

Thanks in advance!
P.S. I am using unity, so I have all the default Quaternion methods at hand.

Current Code:

```
  Quaternion inputAngle = Quaternion.identity;
            if (Character.IsFacingRight)
                inputAngle = Quaternion.FromToRotation(forwardVector, playerInput);
            else
                inputAngle = Quaternion.FromToRotation(playerInput, forwardVector);
            Quaternion minAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, addedForce.force.angle);
            Quaternion angleRange = Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, addedForce.force.angleRange);
            Quaternion maxAngle = angleRange * minAngle;

            // var yaw = Math.Atan2(2.0 * (inputAngle.y * inputAngle.z + inputAngle.w * inputAngle.x), inputAngle.w * inputAngle.w - inputAngle.x * inputAngle.x - inputAngle.y * inputAngle.y + inputAngle.z * inputAngle.z);
            // var pitch = Math.Asin(-2.0 * (inputAngle.x * inputAngle.z - inputAngle.w * inputAngle.y));
            float roll = (float)Math.Atan2(2.0 * (inputAngle.x * inputAngle.y + inputAngle.w * inputAngle.z), inputAngle.w * inputAngle.w + inputAngle.x * inputAngle.x - inputAngle.y * inputAngle.y - inputAngle.z * inputAngle.z);

            Quaternion correctedRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, roll / Mathf.PI * 180F);

            float endAngleZ = ClampRotation2(correctedRotation.eulerAngles.z, minAngle.eulerAngles.z, maxAngle.eulerAngles.z);

            Quaternion endAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, endAngleZ);
```

ClampRotation2:

```
public static float ClampRotation2(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < 0) angle += 360;

    if (max < 0) max += 360;

    if (min < 0) min += 360;
    if (min > max) min -= 360;

    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Can you explain your question more? Maybe what you are doing? Also, it would be good to add what(code) you have tried in your question.

Comment: @Programmer Updated post to include the current code I am using. The problem is simple: I have 3 angles: min, max, and inputAngle and I want inputAngle to be between min and max always

Comment: Ok, what is wrong with the current code? `Mathf.Clamp` should do fine....

Comment: @Programmer Not really, as mentioned in the example : range of [-45,45] and input angle of 225 will return 45 but it should return -45, because on the trigonometric circle 225 is closer to -45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I found the solution which clamps the angle correctly in all cases,

Brought to you by `Quaternion.Angle()` I present :

```
Quaternion inputAngle = Quaternion.identity;
            if (Character.IsFacingRight)
                inputAngle = Quaternion.FromToRotation(forwardVector, playerInput);
            else
                inputAngle = Quaternion.FromToRotation(playerInput, forwardVector);
            Quaternion minAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, addedForce.force.angle);
            Quaternion angleRange = Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, addedForce.force.angleRange);
            Quaternion maxAngle = angleRange * minAngle;

            float roll = (float)Math.Atan2(2.0 * (inputAngle.x * inputAngle.y + inputAngle.w * inputAngle.z), inputAngle.w * inputAngle.w + inputAngle.x * inputAngle.x - inputAngle.y * inputAngle.y - inputAngle.z * inputAngle.z);
            float correctedRotation = roll / Mathf.PI * 180F;

            float minAngleF = minAngle.eulerAngles.z;
            float maxAngleF = maxAngle.eulerAngles.z;

            if (correctedRotation < 0) correctedRotation += 360;

            if (maxAngleF < 0) maxAngleF += 360;

            if (minAngleF < 0) minAngleF += 360;
            if (minAngleF > maxAngleF) minAngleF -= 360;

            if (correctedRotation < minAngleF || correctedRotation > maxAngleF)
            {
                float rotationToMax = Quaternion.Angle(Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, correctedRotation), Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, maxAngleF));
                float rotationToMin = Quaternion.Angle(Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, correctedRotation), Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, minAngleF));
                if (Mathf.Abs(rotationToMax) < Mathf.Abs(rotationToMin))
                    correctedRotation = maxAngleF;
                else
                    correctedRotation = minAngleF;
            }
            Quaternion endAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0F, 0F, correctedRotation);
```

Comment: Ah, we meet again my nemesis.  `Quaternion`...someday I will understand you.