# Rotate object with RotateAround and give it a limit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object in my scene that rotate (**RotateAround**) by the mouse swipe. and I want to give the object some rotation limits, for example -45 and 45 degree for the X axis, so when its rotation become 45 degree it can't go beyond it.

So I tried **Mathf.Clamp** method in my script as you see bellow, and its working fine for the Y axis, the object rotate around his X axis and didn't go beyond the Y limits. but in the X axis, when the object's Y rotation reach O it change immediately to 30 degree with a weird rotation! Can you please tell what's wrong in my code?

**Rotation scripts:**

```
float sensitivity = 10f;
Vector3 firstPressPos;
Vector3 secondPressPos;
float minRotationX = 45;
float maxRotationX = 100;
float minRotationY = 30;
float maxRotationY = 30;

void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //save began touch 2d point
        firstPressPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        //save ended touch 2d point
        secondPressPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

        if (firstPressPos != secondPressPos)
        {
            float RotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            float RotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, RotX);
            transform.RotateAround(Vector3.right, -RotY);

            Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
            angles.x = Mathf.Clamp(angles.x, minRotationX, maxRotationX);
            angles.y = Mathf.Clamp(angles.y, -minRotationY, maxRotationY);
            angles.z = 0;
            transform.eulerAngles = angles;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity - Clamp Rotation between arbitrary angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492004/unity-clamp-rotation-between-arbitrary-angles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the editor, rotation values are between -180 and 180, but in transform.eulerAngles they are actually between 0 and 360.

So you need to adjust the value of your angle before clamping it.

```
if(angles.y > 180)
{
    angles.y -= 180f;
}

angles.y = Mathf.Clamp(angles.Y, minY, maxY);
```

Comment: Yes you're right, its -30 and 30, but how can I use this code? and where should I call the angles.x?

Comment: @Taik The code for the y and z component is the same. However, you cannot clamp the value for x, so you are using 2 if statements that check if the rotation is above +30 or below -30 and assign its value.

Comment: thanks, it works fine for the right angles, but for the left it's not, when the object rotation become less than 0 the object move immediately to -30 degree! and the object become fix and can't rotate at this point!

Comment: @Taik Alright, let me try another solution. I really have to go after that so if it doesnt work keep looking for help

Comment: I've find the solution, its should be (angles.y < 330) instead of (angles.y < 350)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Taik Ye my bad, I confused 180 and 360 and did 380 - 30 by accident. Glad it works tho